# VBA to fill formula down until last row in empty column

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have a report with a row count that changes daily. I need to autofill column C with a formula down to the last row of column B (columns A and B have different row counts, if that matters).

I have the formula in C2 (and a header in C1), how do I get vba to copy the formula in C2 down to the same row number as column B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let `C2` *Autofill* the column `C` until the last populated cell in column `B`:

```
With Sheets("Report")
  .Range("C2").AutoFill .Range("C2:C" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row)
End With
```